# WPF Popup element appears differently on different computers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I am writing an WPF application  using .NET 4.0.
I have a grid and inside of it I have a popup window.
I implement a dragging behavior for this pop up and resizing.
My XAML code looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid" >
<Popup PlacementTarget={Binding ElementName="MyGrid"} Placement=RelativePoint />
<Grid>
```

On my PC everything is working o.k, but when I am checking it on my laptop (which by the way has on it .NET 4.5) its not working well, the popup is not in it's right location.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain or provide a screenshot of the two different behaviours?

Comment: I don't know how can I add screenshot but I will try to explain more.
On My PC, The popup appears on the left upper corner of the Grid, and on my laptop it appears left to the upper left corner. Meaning all the relative issues is behaving differenty

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing is because this behavior can be different based on a setting in the registry.

There may exist a string value **MenuDropAlignment** with value **1** in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
```

Or it may not exist and these two cases causes the different behavior.
Think that the default mode is that the string value exist. In our office we have 5 Windows 8.1 machines where it exist and 1 Windows 8.1 machine where it is left out.